# Could not redirect by ?lang= parametr

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Greeting!
I'm trying to make redirect via htaccess
the URL

> http://domain.com/?lang=ru

need to be redirected to

> http://domain.com

I tried:

```
#ATTEMPT 1
RewriteRule  ^(.*)lang=ru$ $1 [L,R=301]

#ATTEMPT 2
RedirectMatch   301 ^(.*)lang=ru(.*)$   /

#ATTEMPT 3
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^(.*)lang=ru(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /
```

But nothing is working. Is any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this: observe the question mark:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^.*lang=ru.*$
RewriteRule ^  /? [R=301,L]
```